# Adding validations to marketing automation activity type parameters

Tags: validation, marketing-automation

I'm using Sitecore 9.3

Is it possible to add Sitecore validations to the parameters of a marketing automation activity type? I have a parameter called "Title" for example, and I'd like to add a length validator to it.

I tried checking the "Validation Rules" of the Parameter item, but they are mostly validations related to the content editor, and I can only choose "item" validators from within them, not "field" validators.

I've been searching but I couldn't find any information related to this, is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for a custom activity type you will have to do the validation in the client-side JavaScript code for the Activity. I am not aware of any way to achieve this in the Sitecore activity parameters item that will be reflected in the Marketing Automation UI.